# How to create multiple lines of text in android?

Tags: android, textview

In my project I need to display the instructions page. The page consists of 8 instructions. So do we need to create **8 textviews** to display those instructions? Is it possible to display all those instructions using one single textview?

[I read about multi-line textviews](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-basic-text-controls/).

But for my case can I do so to display all 8 instructions in one textview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\n` new line character from string resource or thru code:`textView.setText("1st line\n 2nd line");`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I recall, the newline character \n is recognised when used in strings.xml, so you could declare your instructions there and reference it in the layout. I never found a way to do it within the layout XML itself, but there may be something.

**Edit:** for clarity - I mean using the escaped character, e.g.:

```
<string name="instructions">Line 1\nLine 2</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html to format your string: `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("item 1<br>item 2<br>"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use: StringBuilder to it.